# Kubernetes CrashLoopBackOff after pod create pulling image from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, kubernetes, digital-ocean

On a Digital Ocean Kubernetes Cluster I am trying to create a pod using a Docker image pulled from Docker Hub but it keeps failing with CrashLoopBackOff and restarting. The image is a Rails app in a docker container and is quite large. I suspect that Kubernetes is restarting the pod before the image can load.

Here are the errors:

> kubectl get pods -o wide NAME                                   READY 
>   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
>   exactpos-deployment-864c768bff-zr86t   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   10
>   27m       10.244.66.4   sleepy-nobel-3v8a
>   nginx-deployment-7d69d57649-97w92      1/1       Running            0 
>   40m       10.244.66.7   sleepy-nobel-3v8a
>
> Events:   Type     Reason     Age      From               Message
>   ----     ------     ----                ----                        -------   Normal   Scheduled  27m                 default-scheduler           Successfully assigned default/exactpos-deployment-864c768bff-zr86t to
>   sleepy-nobel-3v8a
>
> Normal   Pulled     26m (x4 over 27m)   kubelet, sleepy-nobel-3v8a 
>   Successfully pulled image
>   "index.docker.io/markhorrocks/exactpos_web:prod"
>
> Normal   Created    26m (x4 over 27m)   kubelet, sleepy-nobel-3v8a 
>   Created container
>
> Normal   Started    26m (x4 over 27m)   kubelet, sleepy-nobel-3v8a 
>   Started container
>
> Normal   Pulling    26m (x5 over 27m)   kubelet, sleepy-nobel-3v8a 
>   pulling image "index.docker.io/markhorrocks/exactpos_web:prod"
>
> Warning  BackOff    2m (x117 over 27m)  kubelet, sleepy-nobel-3v8a 
>   Back-off restarting failed container

Here is my yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
  name: exactpos-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: exactpos-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: exactpos-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: exactpos
          image: index.docker.io/markhorrocks/exactpos_web:prod
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: [ "echo", "SUCCESS" ]
      imagePullSecrets:
         - name: dockerhub-cred
```

Comment: Have you checked logs for the related Pod: `kubectl logs exactpos-deployment-864c768bff-zr86t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i sat on this kind of problem for about 18 hours or more.

the solution was simple, as usual.
simply check your /etc/resolv.conf in your *workers* have proper DNS resolution.
like this:

> vi /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8 (new line)
nameserver 8.8.4.4

restart the bad pods by deleting them.

this is 4 year's old question. but i never saw my answer on the internet anywhere.